# ashx control returning image, jquery get size on load or .NET OnLoad methods not working

Tags: jquery, onload, ashx, pageload

I have an ASHX handler returning an image on page load. I need to add a class to the image dynamically depending on the dimensions of the image. I have tried doing this using the following methods:

**Code Behind Method**

*cs*

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
    image1.ImageUrl = "get_image.ashx?id=" + id;
}

public void classify_image_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(image1.Width.Value > image1.Height.Value)
    {
        image1.CssClass = "landscape";
    }
    else
    {
        image1.CssClass = "portrait";
    }
}
```

*html*

```
<asp:Image ID="image1" runat="server" OnLoad="classify_image_Load" />
```

This works on initial load, however on any postbacks (uploading a new image/rotating/cropping) it fails to apply the class correctly.

**jQuery Method**

*js*

```
$(window).load(function(){

    $('#image1').load(function() {
        if($(this).width() > $(this).height())
        {
            $(this).attr('class', 'landscape');
        } else {
            $(this).attr('class', 'portrait');
        }
    });

});
```

This method doesn't work at all, the image has no class assigned to it. I'm not sure if this is a timing issue with the ashx control or what.

**ASHX Code**

```
public class get_image : IHttpHandler
{
    string file_path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["file_path"].ToString();
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Clear();
        Image img;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.QueryString["id"]))
        {
            int id;
            if (context.Request.QueryString["id"].IndexOf('?') > 0)
            {
                id = Int32.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["id"].Split('?')[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                id = Int32.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
            }

            dbclassDataContext db = new dbclassDataContext();
            photo d = (from p in db.photos
                       where p.id == id
                       select p).SingleOrDefault();

            if (d != null)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(d.filename))
                {
                    img = Image.FromFile(file_path + "\\" + d.filename);
                    context.Response.ContentType = "image/" + d.filetype;
                    img.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, get_format(d.filetype));
                }
                else
                {
                    img = Image.FromFile(file_path + "\\no_image.jpg");
                    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                    img.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                img = Image.FromFile(file_path + "\\no_image.jpg");
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                img.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            img = Image.FromFile(file_path + "\\no_image.jpg");
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            img.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
        img.Dispose();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private ImageFormat get_format(string ftype)
    {
        switch (ftype)
        {
            case "jpeg":
                return ImageFormat.Jpeg;
            case "png":
                return ImageFormat.Png;
            case "gif":
                return ImageFormat.Gif;
            default:
                return ImageFormat.Jpeg;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Linq to pull the location and type from the database based on the users ID, I then return the image to the requesting page. This seems to be working fine but I included it in case there may be any issues I overlooked.

**Question**

I need to dynamically classify the Image based on its dimensions, I can do this either in .NET code behind or with jQuery. What am I doing wrong with the above methods that is causing it to not work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .load event can have problems if the image is loaded from browser cache (see http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ ) - maybe you could try either disabling the caching or appending a time value to the image so the browser doesn't cache it, in case it's that issue that's hitting?

Comment: I wrote a function to prevent caching but forgot to wrap the image URL in it. :P Thanks